# Going below zero in unsigned integer operations

Tags: c, algorithm, unsigned-integer

I want to deduce a list of 16-bit unsigned integers from another list of 16-bit unsigned integers.

For example, given the list:

```
10000, 12349, 32333, 3342
```

and I know the first integer of the other list is 0, now I want to deduce the rest. The mapping is to subtract 10000 from them, I got

```
0, 2349, 22333, 58878
```

where 58878 = (3342-10000+65536) modulo 65536 as the result of a wrapping.

The pseudocode is something like：

```
 void deduce(u_int16_t list1[100], u_int16_t *list2[100], u_int16_t first)
 {
      int diff = first - list1[0];
      for (i = 0; i < 100; i++)
          (*list2)[i] = (list1[i] + diff + 65536) % 65536;
 }
```

but we know that there is no minus number in unsigned integers.

so how to do the mapping(or deduction)?

thanks!

Comment: Your question is extremely unclear.

Comment: what do you actually want the answer to be when the input is 3342?

Comment: So just write the code using unsigned integers and the overflow / wrap happens automatically.

Comment: but if `diff` is of type `int`, then `list1[i]+diff` returns a type `int` but not `u_int16_t`. so the problem is how to manipulate `diff` and the `minus/plus` calculation

Comment: if you want it all to just happen automatically then make diff be u_int16_t instead of int.

Comment: So what's wrong with making diff `uint16_t` [or `u_int16_t` in your code].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*unsigned* integers variables can be subtracted more than they contain - if I understand correctly the question.

```
u_int16_t u = 10;
u -= 20; // => u = u - 20;
printf("%x, %u\n", u, u); // => fff6, 65526
```

The difference is

- when displayed, *u* does not show a negative value - ie the MSb (most significant bit, ie bit 15) is interpreted (here) as 2<sup>15</sup>, the next as 2<sup>14</sup> etc...
- when extended (eg to 32 bits) the MBb is not propagated from bit 16 to bit 31 (as they would be if signed) - they're `0`
- when *right shifted* the value MSb is always `0` (would be the same as previous MSb if signed, e.g `1` for a negative value)

So your mapping will keep working with `u_int16_t` (and you don't need the `%` modulo 65536 if you work with that type everywhere since anyway the values are on 16 bits - the modulo is implicit).

Comment: What is `10 -= 20` supposed to mean?

Comment: @AnT Fixed (finally!)

Answer (score 1):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <inttypes.h>

void deduce(uint16_t list1[], uint16_t list2[], size_t size){
    int32_t i, first = list1[0];

    for(i=0;i<size;++i){
    //  list2[i]= list1[i] - first;
        int32_t wk = list1[i];
        wk -= first;
        if(wk<0)
            wk += 65536;
        list2[i] = wk;
    }
}

int main(void){
    uint16_t list1[100] = {
        10000,
        12349,
        32333,
         3342
    };
    uint16_t list2[100];
    int i;

    deduce(list1, list2, 4);
    for(i = 0; i<4; ++i)
        printf("%5" PRIu16 "\n", list2[i]);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite understand your question, but if what you want is to subtract every element of the first list by the different between the first element of both list. This code should work.

```
void deduce(uint16_t list1[], uint16_t list2[], int size)
{
    uint16_t diff = list1[0] - list2[0];
    int i;
    for (i=0; i<size; i++)
        list2[i] = list1[i] - diff;
}
```

You don't need to pass list2 as u_int16_t* list2[] because you actually can edit the content of the array with u_int16_t list2[]. Only use u_int16_t* list2[] if you want to do dynamic memory allocation in this function.